# Angularjs: checking radio box automatically

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, checked

Here is my radio buttons code

```
<input type="radio"  ng-model="choice.phone" ng-value="1" name="phone" ng-  
click="setPhoneType('cell')"> cell phone<br/>

<input type="radio"  ng-model="choice.phone" ng-value="2" name="phone" ng-
click="setPhoneType('Home')"> Home phone <br/>
```

Now when a user choose any of them then below radio button should be checked as default

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="choice.International" ng-value="1" 
name="international" ng-click="setChoiceType('Inter')" ng-checked="choice.phone"> International call
```

The js code is as follow:

```
setPhoneType = function setPhoneType(phoneType) {
                    $scope.phone = phoneType;
                    $scope.setChoiceType('Inter');
                    return;
 },
 setChoiceType = function setChoiceType(callType) {
                    $scope.international = callType;
                    return;
                },
```

The problem is that when I choose any `phone` then the `Inter` is checked automatically but later on the value is undefined, It goes to `setChoiceType` but after that choice.International is undefined. If I manually choose `Inter (by clicking on it)` it is fine.

Comment: A fiddle or plunkr will make it much easier to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your radio buttons are bound to properties of the choice object.  But, setPhoneType and setChoiceType update values directly on the scope - not the choice object.  Also, I think you want to use value, not ng-value.

[Here is plnkr](http://plnkr.co/3rNYt3r9ernMTV0DQN4h).